# Broken setup.py implementation for a minimal module

Tags: python

I forked the nice module [multiscorer](https://github.com/StKyr/multiscorer) and I am trying to turn it into a package that I could install in different environments.

My fork can be found [here](https://github.com/drorata/multiscorer/tree/create-package). The steps I took are

- Create a new environment (using conda) and activate it
- `python setup.py install` from the root directory of the fork
- In a new terminal, activate the environment and move to some arbitrary location. Start `ipython` and try `from multiscorer import MultiScorer`

I get the following error `ImportError: cannot import name 'MultiScorer'`. Note however, that `import multiscorer` works just fine. What do I have to change in the code to enable an installation using `python setup.py install`?

**Another attempt:** I tried to replace `packages=['multiscorer']` with `py_modules=['multiscorer.multiscorer']`. Didn't help...

Comment: Are you sure that you do not have a spelling Problem? `from multiscorer import MultiScorer` -->`ImportError: cannot import name 'Multiscorer'`

Comment: @am2 That was a typo. The problem is still around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `setup.py` is alright. The problem is the package structure. Right now the correct way to import the `Multiscorer` class is this: `from multiscorer.multiscorer import Multiscorer`. The first `multiscorer` is for the folder (package) of the same name and the second `multiscorer` is for the `multiscorer.py` module inside the package.

[The docs](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html#creating-the-scaffolding) recommend putting all your code inside the `__init__.py` for such small packages.
If your codebase later grows too large for one file, you can start introducing other modules and use the `__init__.py` for exposing classes/functions on the package level.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I tried to import the wrong thing. The following: `from multiscorer.multiscorer import MultiScorer` works.

I am now wondering is this *the pythonic* way.

Comment: It seems a bit too verbose to be _pythonic_, imho. More so since you can avoid the second `multiscorer` (see my answer) :)